# Using Pandas how can I split a number into categories or tiers

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to split a column, representing a number of days that attract different charges, into tiers.  For example:  A rail-car is sitting on a customer's location for 11 days.  Typically the customer will get 5 "free" days to unload the car, then another 5 days at $50/day, and then all other days may be $75 per day.

So in this case I would like to generate the **tier.X.days** like:

| days | tier.1.threshold | tier.2.threshold | tier.3.threshold | tier.1.days | tier.2.days | tier.3.days |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | 5 | 5 | NaN | 5 | 5 | 1 |
| 3 | 5 | 5 | NaN | 3 | 0 | 0 |
| 7 | 5 | 5 | NaN | 5 | 2 | 0 |
| 7 | 3 | 3 | NaN | 3 | 3 | 1 |

From a table with just the days and thresholds.  Wondering if there is an elegant way of doing it.  The number of tiers is variable as well but I can generate those in a different way.  In the end I would like to easily generate **tier.X.charge** which would be **tier.X.days** times **tier.X.rate** (the 5 days X $50/days for example).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cumsum` to calculate the accumulate thresholds, then subtract them off the days, clipping negative values to `0`:

```
# extract the thresholds
thresh = df.filter(like='threshold')

# cumsum of the threshold 
cumsums = thresh.cumsum(1).shift(1,fill_value=0,axis=1)

# subtract the accumulate thresholds from the days
# then clipping, 
out = np.minimum(-cumsums.sub(df['days'], axis='rows'), thresh.fillna(cumsums)).clip(0)

# also
# out = (-cumsums.sub(df['days'], axis='rows')).clip(lower=0, upper=thresh.fillna(cumsums))
```

Output:

```
   tier.1.threshold  tier.2.threshold  tier.3.threshold
0               5.0               5.0               1.0
1               3.0               0.0               0.0
2               5.0               2.0               0.0
3               3.0               3.0               1.0
```